# I get Unauthorized error while trying to login from a firebase deployed Angular project to a heroku Springboot app

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jwt

I'm currently developing this project that connects an Angular Project deployed in Firebase to a Springboot App deployed in Heroku. The problem is when I try to access through the Login it doesn't permit me to do so. I don't know if the problem is in the CORS or the JWT. When I was working locally I had no problems whatsoever.

Auth.Service in Angular
[image: Auth.Service in Angular]

Guard.Service in Angular
[image: Guard.Service in Angular]

Environment.prod in Angular
[image: Environment.prod in Angular]

JwtEntryPoint
[image: JwtEntryPoint]

MainSecuritySprinboot
[image: MainSecuritySprinboot]

AuthController1 SpringBoot
[image: AuthController1 SpringBoot]

AuthController2 SpringBoot
[image: AuthController2 SpringBoot]

[Adding the error message in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE7OK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWC5Q.png)

Comment: if you share a MVCE, that will make it easy to answer

Comment: I'm sorry i'm really noob in this área. What is a MVCE?

Comment: minimum verifiable complete example... check stackblitz, you'll be hooked

Comment: Also you could add some screen shots from the network and console, to see if there's any error